# Can you use getElementByID to display the content of multiple div wrappers

Tags: javascript, html

I am using getElementById to toggle the display of a block in html. The block I am toggling is wrapped in a div like so:

```
<div id="SunMotion">
    <br>
    <p>
      Toggle the switch to run "24HourCycle.py"
    </p>
    <label class="switch">
      <input id="check3" type="hidden">
      <article>
        <button class="program" id="check3" id="script1" onclick="check3()" data-fileName="24HourCycle.py">24 Hour Cycle</button>
      </article>
    </label>
  </div>
```

This is activated using the button:

```
 <button class="button button1" onclick="SunMotion()">
            Motion of the Sun
          </button>
```

The button calls the function in javascript which displays the div using its Id:

```
document.getElementById("SunMotion").style.display = 'none';
function SunMotion() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SunMotion");
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("SunMotion").checked = false;
  }
}
```

This works fine until I try to do the same thing with a different block. with a new function specific to that button:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="SunMotion()">
            Motion of the Sun
</button>
<button class="button button1" onclick="Hologram()">
            Hologram Shapes
</button>
<br>
    <div id="Hologram">
        <br>
        <p>
        Toggle the switch to run the Hologram program
        </p>
        <label class="switch">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <input id="check12" type="hidden">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="item1"><button id="check12" id="grd" id="script1" onclick="check12()" data-fileName="red.py">Red</button></div>
            <input id="check13" type="hidden">   

        </label>
    </div>
<br>
    <div id="SunMotion">
        <p>
        Toggle the switch to run "24HourCycle.py"
        </p>
        <label class="switch">
        <input id="check3" type="hidden">
        <article>
            <button class="program" id="check3" id="script1" onclick="check3()" data-fileName="24HourCycle.py">24 Hour Cycle</button>
        </article>
        </label>
    </div>
<br>

<script>
document.getElementById("Hologram").style.display = 'none';
function Hologram() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Hologram");
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("Hologram").checked = false;
  }
}
document.getElementById("SunMotion").style.display = 'none';
function SunMotion() {
  var x = document.getElementById("SunMotion");
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("SunMotion").checked = false;
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you've tried to do the same with a different block?

Comment: Yeah so I used a new function that is specific to each button so with two buttons I have two functions. I edited the original for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

if you want use that function on another div, you need to use getElementByClass instead. you can check it [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
or, if you still want to use id, just send that id as parameter.

```
function SunMotion(id) {
var x = document.getElementById(id);
 if (x.style.display === 'none') {
   x.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
   x.style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(id).checked = false;
 }
}
```

and, to call that just paste an Id to that function.

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="SunMotion('SunMotion')">
    Motion of the Sun
</button>
```

Sorry, Typo. you can check my recheck my answer. my Edit is :

```
onclick="SunMotion('SunMotion')"
```

Please noted that I changing " by ' in parameter.

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble using the id as a parameter. could you show me another example?